# Suggestions on How to Migrate from Magento 1.1.7 to 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade, migration

I've been tasked with upgrading a now non-functional web site using very old Magento 1.1.7 to a more recent version (latest currently being 1.9).  I'm an experienced web developer but am brand spanking new to Magento.

While doing my homework and getting up to speed on Magento, I thought I'd ask the experts how to best go about doing this?  Support from the company hosting the site suggested that it would probably be necessary to stand up a new site with an up-to-date version and then try to migrate the old data.

Do you agree that this is the best approach?  If so, can someone please point me toward resources (if any) that might help me better understand how to map/migrate data between these two versions?  Or provide any general advice that may help me accomplish this?

Comment: @Serpyre, I think this should be posted as an answer.

Comment: Thanks very much Serpyre!  Sorry you've had a bad experience here.  I appreciate you finding a way to share your thoughts anyway!

Answer (score 2):

According to [Magento's Wiki](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/upgrading_magento) 1.1.7 doesn't even have an upgrade path to 1.9. And I doubt any extensions or themes installed would actually upgrade to 1.9. So migrating the data is really your only true option.

Comment: Do you know if there's any kind of resource that would map the 1.1.7 database to the 1.9 database to perform the migration?  Or does the database change so little from release to release that the mapping should be pretty obvious once I get in there?  Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: I would pull a blank export from both 1.1.7 and 1.9 and compare them. They maybe very similar. However, I would believe the 1.9 export would have more fields that can be entered.

Answer (score 1):

The steps I would take are:

- clone current db
- install 1.9, point at new db
- verify all data from db is linked into Magento 1.9 correctly
- get latest version of any extensions needed
- install extensions, one-by-one
- test each extensions operation and any affect on related classes, templates, layouts
- install theme, if any
- test pages/templates which your theme overrides
- test CMS pages, static blocks
- multi-browser, multi-device testing
- launch

Comment: Thanks Joshua34com for your list of steps -- VERY helpful!  Though if the database is just a clone of the current one, would it be missing fields/tables added for later releases?  I also saw on the Magneto site where they offer a "database repair tool" that goes from source to target database.  Any experience with that?  Or any idea if that would clean up the database to add the necessary elements?  Thanks again!